# How to use np.arange() to create a 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to recreate a 3D scatter plot figure but I'm having a hard time with getting the range right on the **y axis**.
This is the figure that I am trying to emulate:

[image]

Here's my code for the np.arange():

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15,15])

z = 520 * np.random.random(100)
x = np.arange(0,20,0.2)
y = np.arange(0,20,0.2)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3, projection='3d')
ax3.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=14)
ax3.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=14)
ax3.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=14)                          
ax3.scatter3D(x,y,z, c=z, cmap='jet')
ax3.view_init(25,45);
```

This is the output:

[image]

I'm not trying to make it look exactly the same with the angle but I need to get the axis plots correct.

Comment: You deleted your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74000238/7758804). Go look at the bottom.

Comment: Show all of your code for plotting.

Comment: You wanted to vote to close my other question so I deleted it. This is more of a specific question.

Comment: I did vote to close it, because technically there wasn't anything wrong with it. You just deleted it before I could add the more succinct code.

Comment: You need to do `x = np.random.uniform(7.5, 12.5, 100)` , `y = np.random.uniform(7.5, 12.5, 100)` and `ax.set(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 20))`. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY7XM.png). Probably use `np.random.uniform` for `z` too, and add `zlim=(0, 520)`

Comment: This gives me a similar output. The y axis from the first figure still doesn't match my output.

Comment: Something like `ax.set_yticks([0, 5, 10, 15, 20])` if the purpose of the question is just to set the axis ticks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not produce the output I wanted. I went back and edited my original question with a "cleaner" code in my first question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000238/how-to-create-3d-scatter-subplots-with-different-angles. I saw the option you offered but I have to follow a certain format on the data for the 3-D scattered points. I apologize if I can't explain it clearer. I'm a student and still trying to understand this.

Comment: Actually you are passing equal arrays for `x` and `y`. This way your data are all located in the plane `x=y`, to do this "dispersion" effect you need to vary the `x` and `y` values within the desired range. For example, try building your `x` and `y` with `x = 20*np.random.rand(100)` and `y = 20*np.random.rand(100)`